# How to change redis source code?

Tags: redis

I am making changes in the redis source code so that everytime the user sets a key, instead of printing "OK" it prints something else.
But this change is not getting reflected.

I also tried uninstalling redis, modifying the redis source code and then installing it again. But still it doesnt work.

Does it need to be compiled or something?

Comment: Redis is written in ANSI C, of course you should compile it.

Comment: How should it be compiled? Should each .c file be compiled individually?

Comment: if you're working if the official source (https://github.com/antirez/redis), just run `make`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[https://www.heychinaski.com/blog/2013/10/14/a-look-at-the-redis-source-code/comment-page-1/](http://web.archive.org/web/20141016080003/https://www.heychinaski.com/blog/2013/10/14/a-look-at-the-redis-source-code/comment-page-1/)   This should help you change redis code. Here there is an excellent example given. They have added a new command "rand" to redis command set.

I'll summarize the steps to add a command in redis :

1. In redisCommandTable, you need to add the specifications of the new command- the command name, its args etc.
2. Then you need to define a prototype of the function that will be called when this command is executed in src/redis.h
3. Define the function in src/redis.c.
4. Give 'make' to compile.

Comment: @gunr2171 : Is my answer fine now?